# How can you find where python imported a particular module from?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

How can you find where python imported a particular module from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each module object has a `__file__` attribute:

```
import module

print module.__file__
```

Some modules are part of the Python executable; these will not have the attribute set.

Demo:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> urllib2.__file__
'/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.pyc'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.__file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

You could also run Python in *verbose* mode, with the [`-v` command line switch](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-v) or the [`PYTHONVERBOSE` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONVERBOSE); Python then prints out *every imported file* as it takes place.